# Reading large XML files with MATLAB

Tags: xml, matlab

After much searching online tonight I've failed to find a solid solution to this problem.

I have some large XML files, more specifically N42 schema XML ([link](http://physics.nist.gov/Divisions/Div846/Gp4/ANSIN4242/xml.html)), which I'd like to read into MATLAB. Size wise, these files are anything from 50MB - 300MB i.e. large.

I only need a couple of the tags within the file but it's proving very difficult to get to the data! The standard MATLAB xmlread() function uses DOM access which very quickly runs into memory problems and takes forever.

Is there any easy option to do this with MATLAB e.g. SAX or using regular expressions? I'm happy if it isn't an elegant solution, just something to allow me to access the data.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [java within matlab](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/matlab_external/bringing-java-classes-and-methods-into-matlab-workspace.html). I would use the java sax parser.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Are there any simple matlab/java/sax examples?